Identify a “6C” SOIC-6 IC inside a Canon Vixia HG20 LCD display
I have had a Canon Vixia HG20 for 15 years. Recently, I noticed a black LCD screen, so I set myself to take a closer look at it.
Before replacing the flex cable and/or the LCD, I'd like to check the electronics on the LCD board. There are 3 ICs I could not find any information about, including https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/
I am splitting this into 3 different questions, and this is the second one, so users will have the right chance of getting an accepted answer individually.
The IC in question has a marking “6C”. It has 6 terminals, and its approximate dimensions are 1.6mm x 1.1mm. These were taken with a caliper, not a microscope, so there is some error there.
It is surely much smaller than a SOIC-6 and I am not sure what case is that. Can anyone point me to its datasheet?



and its approximate dimensions are 1.6mm x 1.1mm it looks like a QFN6 or DFN6. This may help to narrow your search.

It's a Toshiba RN4983FE dual digital transistor.


(Source: prom.ua)

Thank you for the source, I didn't know it! I've had a few similar questions closed, I didn't know this sort of question is now allowed. Would you mind sharing other sources you might have for this? I'd create a new question for this, but I guess it would also be closed. Here are the sources I know of:  http://chip.tomsk.ru/, http://www.s-manuals.com/smd, http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm

@tfm Identification questions are allowed, but there are three types of questions that often overlap. 1. Datasheet questions - Those are off-topic and will be closed. 2. Identification questions - Those are allowed. 3. Repair questions - Those are allowed if they are kept very specific and show that you know what you're doing. - Your questions basically contains all three, but imo this one is sufficiently focused on identification so that it's on-topic. However, people that interpret the rules strictly might still vote to close because you request a datasheet.

@tfm Regarding the sources. proma.ua is just the source of the image. I don't explicitly search databases because the results are often poor in my experience. I nearly exclusively use google search queries (google has a lot of the databases indexed anyway) and lcsc.com to search for images. I wrote about my process a bit in this answer, but that's really only applicable if you already know the manufacturer. So you can't use this method here.

I see, thank you for the clarifications about what is allowed and what isn't. About proma.ua being just the source of the image, that is curious, because at first I read the text: "Transistor 6C smd. RN4983FE SOT563. Gorenje module. Code: Transistor 6C" after clicking on the link you provided, and I assumed that if I typed that on their search bar I'd find this part. But now that I tested, it didn't come up, which is a weird behavior.

For learning purposes, I'll insist a bit on your search process. I also always try google first, but even the query "sot666 "6c" marking  terminal toshiba" won't bring anything up. So how did you do it?

@tfm I try to find the best search approach first. In this case I tried mainly by searching for the right package name, since the package is not that common. I used this book (page 48&49) to find different names of this package. Often manufacturers have their own name. I tried different ones until I searched ES6 "6C" marking. The third result was this page which has the name of component. I used image search with the components name to find picture to confirm it is the right part.
