Identify a SOT-23 IC inside a Canon Vixia HG20 LCD display
I have had a Canon Vixia HG20 for 15 years. Recently, I noticed a black LCD screen, so I set myself to take a closer look at it.
Before replacing the flex cable and/or the LCD, I'd like to check the electronics on the LCD board. There are 3 ICs I could not find any information about.
I am splitting this into 3 different questions, and this is the third one, so users will have the right chance of getting an accepted answer individually.
The IC in question has a marking “7” "86" and "Z1". It has 5 terminals, and its approximate dimensions are 1.5mm x 1.8mm. These were taken with a caliper, not a microscope, so there is some error there. It is surely smaller than a SOT-23 and I am not sure what case is that. Can anyone point me to its datasheet?



What is pin 5 connected to?

I couldn't find your part but I found this:

from aliexpress described as a NJU77806F3 from Nisshinbo.
The package is SC-88A which most likely corresponds to your measurement.
In the following page you can find all Nisshinbo SC-88A products.
However a few of them contain marking on their datasheet.
I didn't find your exact component so you should consider asking directly to the manufacturer.

Thank you. Can you share what is your source or how you got there? On this post comments:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/710192/identify-a-6c-soic-6-ic-inside-a-canon-vixia-hg20-lcd-display
I explained that I've had some similar questions closed, and that I imagine I can't open a new questions for SMD catalogs/sources. On this same comment, I asked for sources for SMD catalogs. Maybe you could chime in there and contribute to it?

Generally speaking you have a guide there : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component . Usually I just base my search on experience (typical markings format for manufacturers). I also put a lot of importance of the manufacturer of the board. Here it is Canon, a Japanese brand. So I will first take a look on Japanse manufacturers (Toshiba, Rohm ... and finally Nisshinbo in that case). And as you mentionned that the package is smaller than a SOT-23, I found the SC-88A package and so on..
